# Firebase push notification isn't working in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging to send push notification. after receiving push notification I download some additional content and then fire a local notification. This works in foreground but not working in background.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jy_Hlskmiw) on youtube.
Here is my code,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.badge,.sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
    }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    connectFCM()
}

func connectFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
    }
    fireLocalNotification(data:userInfo)// where additional content is downloaded and a local notification is fired
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    token = fcmToken
    sendTokenToServer(token: fcmToken)
    connectFCM()
}
```

I've added these background modes in the info.plist file
[image]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I found the reason why it didn't work. Firebase isn't compatible with VOIP push. so the notifications from Firebase won't wake the app in background.